# Solving a introduction statistics problem

Tags: statistics

$X_{1},X_{2}...,X_{n}$ are independant observations from a random variable $\xi$

For every $X_{k}$ we have that:

$$
t_{k}= \frac{X_{k}-\overline{X}}{S}
$$
Where $\overline{X}= \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} }{n}$ and $S^{2}= \frac{\sum _{i=1}^{n} (X_{i}-\overline{X})^2}{n-1}$

proove that :

$$
|t_{k}| < \frac{n-1}{ \sqrt{n} },k=1,2,....
$$

Question: ***Can you please help me solve this problem and show me a solution?***

Personal solution: Tried to substitude somehow but all I go nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $n\geq 2$. For convenience, let $k=1$. Transform the equality
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline X)=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-n\overline X=0$$
to
$$
(X_1-\overline X) = -\sum_{i=2}^n(X_i-\overline X). 
$$
Squaring both sides and applying the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) get
$$
(X_1-\overline X)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=2}^n(X_i-\overline X)\right)^2 
\leq \sum_{i=2}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2\cdot \sum_{i=2}^n 1^2 = (n-1) \sum_{i=2}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2.
$$
Add $(n-1)(X_1-\overline X)^2 $ to the both sides of the above inequality and obtain
$$
n(X_1-\overline X)^2 \leq (n-1) \sum_{i=2}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2+ (n-1)(X_1-\overline X)^2, $$
$$n(X_1-\overline X)^2 \leq (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2 = (n-1)^2 S^2,$$
$$t_1^2=\dfrac{(X_1-\overline X)^2}{S^2} \leq \dfrac{(n-1)^2}{n}.$$

This inequality is equaivalent to $|t_1|\leq \dfrac{(n-1)}{\sqrt{n}}$.

To obtain strict inequality note that both sides in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality are equal only if 
vectors 
$$((X_2-\overline X),\ldots,(X_n-\overline X))\quad \text{ and } \quad(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{n-1})$$ 
are collinear and then $X_2 =\ldots=X_n$. All other cases provide strict inequality, but in general it does not hold. Say, for samples from discrete distribution the equality $X_2 =\ldots=X_n$ has positive probability.